# LibOpenCM3 vector table is all blocking-handler

Tags: stm32, isr, libopencm3

The answer to this question here
[Libopencm3 interrupt table on STM32F4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710085/libopencm3-interrupt-table-on-stm32f4)
explains the whole mechanism nicely but what I get is **whole vector table filled with blocking handlers**.

I know that because I see it in debugger (apart from the whole thing not working): [disassembly screenshot showing vector table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4fJX.png).

It is as though linker simply ignores my nicely defined interrupt handler function(s), e.g.:

```c
void sys_tick_handler(void)
{
...
}

void tim1_up_isr(void)
{
...
}
```

I am using EmBitz IDE and have followed this tutorial [here](https://github.com/OliviliK/STM32F103/wiki/Tutorial2_LOCM3Template) to get libopencm3 to work (and it does work except for this issue).

I have checked the function names n-fold and have tried several online examples including those from the libopencm3-examples project.

Everything compiles without a glitch and loads into the target board (STM32F103C8) and runs fine - except no ISRs get invoked (I do get interrupt(s) but they get stuck in blocking handlers).

**Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?**

Comment: Is it correct that you have the same issue when building and running projects from libopencm3-examples? If so, how are you building them? Just by running `make` in corresponding project directory? And which OS are you using?

Comment: @Sam, I'm using EmBitz IDE, as stated in the question. I'm running it on a Win 7 VM but don't see how could that be related. Could it be EmBitz issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like linking with standard vector table (from ST's SPL or HAL).

To check this, try to rename your `sys_tick_handler()` to `SysTick_Handler()` and 
`tim1_up_isr()` to `TIM1_UP_IRQHandler()`.

If it works, find file with this `SysTick_Handler` and `TIM1_UP_IRQHandler` (I think, that will be `startup*.s`) and delete it from your project.

Comment: When I rename `sys_tick_handler()` to `SysTick_Handler()` it works. The `SysTick_Handler` symbol is used only in the file "startup_stm32f10x_md.s" which contains the startup code and the vector table definition - are you suggesting to remove this file?

Comment: Actually, this is starting to make sense - the "startup_stm32f10x_md.s" file uses `SysTick_Handler` symbol to populate the vector table but the symbol is defined **only** in that file (as blocking handler) **and** there is no link between it and the `sys_tick_handler` symbol - so no wonder it does not work. It all comes from the tutorial I followed [link](https://github.com/OliviliK/STM32F103/wiki/Tutorial2_LOCM3Template) which suggests to remove LibOpenCM3's "vector_nvic.c" file and introduces the startup file (which apparently is supposed to define the vector table itself).

Comment: OK, found the way how to make it work: at the start of "startup_stm32f10x_md.S" file add `#include <irqhandlers.h>` (which contains only #define's of IRQ handler alternative names), add `#define SysTick_Handler sys_tick_handler` (because it is not defined in "irqhandlers.h" for some reason) and add another search path to the project options ("C:\CommonLibs\libopencm3\include\libopencmsis\stm32\f1").

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it led to the solution. Thanks Alexey!