# How can I set an interrupt service routine on ARM Cortex M using picolibc?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m

[Picolibc](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc) provides startup routines, including linker scripts, for bare metal ARM development, making it easy to write small embedded projects without using IDEs.

How can I define interrupt service routines under that? I assume picolibc defines the ISRs using weak symbols that I can just override, but can't find any docs or examples.  At the least, what are the correct names to use?

Comment: You have the source code. Check how the vector table is populated.

Comment: Your inability to find the documentation perhaps needs addressing.  The CMSIS documentation and conventions for interrupt handling are documented at https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__NVIC__gr.html.  It is exactly as you "assumed", so it is not clear why you are asking the question.  Noting that the "device specific vectors" are, well.... device specific, and the names vary - consult your part's documentation (or the exported `xxxx_IRQHandler` symbols in startup_xxxx.s.

Comment: @Clifford The device specific interrupts are _numbered_, not _named_.  But once you use a lib which defines symbols, you need to match the _name_ you use to the symbol they define.  One setup might define it as `_reset`, the other as `______RESET____`, they'll both work as long as you follow it.

Comment: @Clifford See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38661382/785494 for libopencm3; it explains the weak symbols clearly.  I'm looking for the same for picolib.

Comment: Ok, Picolib is not CMSIS compliant (at least in this respect).  Which seems like a poor decision as it precludes the use of a great deal of existing code.  I am taking a look at it now - wait a bit.

Comment: ... For Picolib specifically `main/picocrt/machine/arm/crt0.c` uses an `external` reference to `__interrupt_vector` - I would guess that that is for your application to define. - it would be a table of pointers to functions.  For variants with a relocatable vector table, you can of course map it to something else in any case and set the vectors art run-time.  The Picolib does not really prevent you from doing whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out altos which does this: https://git.gag.com/?p=fw/altos;a=blob;f=src/stm/ao_interrupt.c;h=0d6e450f581b1911e4ae3e3089154c5348ef1577;hb=HEAD has an interrupt table filled with a pile of symbols which are weakly aliased to no-op functions. Define any of these elsewhere and it will replace the weak symbol. The core picolibc code has a similar example here: https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc/blob/main/newlib/libc/picolib/machine/arm/interrupt.c , but as most of a NVIC table is soc-specific, that can't have useful names for the functions.

Comment: Thanks! And thank you for making picolabc! But I'm still not 100% clear on the answer.  Understood that picolibc can't define useful names, and understood I can find them in the datasheet.  But how do I e.g. define one ISR that I want to implement, while still keeping picolibc's definitions for the ones it does (both `_start` and any defaults).  Perhaps an example would help?